# Akeeba Release System – Update Streams non sef url

Tags: one-click-updates, extension-update

i have created a new component and when i want add auto update to it using the Akeeba Release System compoennt , also i have done avery thing , but when i want add the : server xml file

```
<updateservers>
<server type="extension" priority="1" name="WHM Portfolio">http://site.com/index.php?
```

option=com_ars&view=update&task=stream&format=xml&id=1&dummy=extension.xml

it give this error :

```
Warning
JInstaller: :Install: Can't find Joomla XML setup file.
Error
Unable to find install package
```

also this is only because of the safe url when use any other ull like :
http://site.com/extension.xml  it works

also i have added  the  "&dummy=extension.xml" to the Akeeba Release System – Update Streams xml url 
but still not work ..

is there any fix for this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ampersands (`&`) have to be escaped in XML. Your URL should look like this:

```
http://site.com/index.php?option=com_ars&amp;view=update&amp;task=stream&amp;format=xml&amp;id=1&amp;dummy=extension.xml
```

Comment: thanks , your solution has fixed the issue ..